# How to factory reset Apple TV without any working remote or Apple ID

Tags: appletv

I got an Apple TV 4k device from a friend, but without the remote. I bought a cheap IR remote to see if I could get this to work.

When I hold the menu and right buttons on the remote, I am taken to a screen where I'm supposed to enter my friend's Apple ID password.  But I am not able to control the cursor, so it would be impossible to enter the password even if I got the password.

I have also tried to control the Apple TV with iPhone or with a Bluetooth keyboard, but for this I would first need to be able to control the Apple TV with a remote to get to settings.

This [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/213353/456326) to a different question mentions a "physical tap" method (the link to apple.com is a 404 though).  It does do something when I try this: I need to enter a 4 digit code that is showing on the iPhone on the Apple TV. But the Apple TV wants me to enter the Apple ID password, which I cannot without a way to control the Apple TV.

It seems my only two options to get this thing to work again are:

- my friend finding the paired remote
- heading to an Apple service centre

Or am I missing something, and is there a way to reset the device without controlling the device without anything paired to it?

Comment: I've reset earlier models of Apple TV using iTunes.

Comment: I've changed the link in the answer you refer to to point to the page on archive.org. It's about Apple TV (3rd generation) though, so it won't help in your case.

Comment: First step would be to get them to dissociate it from their account. idk what happens next though, without a remote.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to enter the PIN using the iPhone Apple TV remote function of Control Center. I have found that the old Apple TV Remote App does not work on newer Apple TVs, as it has been replaced with the built-in function in Control Center.

Go to Control Center, and look for the Apple TV remote icon. If you don't see it, enable it in Settings>Control Center. It should find the Apple TV and ask for the PIN to connect.

Make sure the Apple TV is on the same network. You may have to use an ethernet cable that is connected to the same network segment at the wifi.

More: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201664